# gradle groovy project dependent on java project

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, eclipse-wtp

```
projects
  -ProjA
     -src/main/java/com/company/One.java
  -ProjB
     -src/main/java/com/company2/Three.java 
     -src/main/groovy/com/company2/Two.groovy
```

ProjB/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

dependencies {
    compile project(':projects:ProjA')
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9'
```

ProjB/Two.groovy

```
    One object=new One();
```

In eclipse,if I run ProjB (Run -> Run On Server ->tomcat), I get

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.company.One
```

Two.groovy is able to use Three.java, but not One.java

Update:Just found out that it has nothing to do with groovy
Even Three.java is not able to access One.java(different project)
Eclipse code completion is working,but doesn't work when 'Run on server'
ProjA just have some come pojo's

Comment: Did you apply `eclipse-wtp` to `allprojects {}`?

Comment: No,ProjA contains just POJO's. Should I apply eclipse-wtp for ProjA also?

Comment: Yes, use `eclipse-wtp` for both projects or simply `eclipse` if you don't use WTP functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eclipse dependent projects not copied to WTP deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493763/eclipse-dependent-projects-not-copied-to-wtp-deployment)

> An Eclipse WTP project that depends on other projects won't deploy those projects' dependencies unless they are WTP projects as well.